# Why is my download attribute not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML-File. I'm trying to put a downloadable image-file on my HTML. For that I used the code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_download_link).

My code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html  >
<html lang="en" style="background:  #fffff0;">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body >
    <div style="padding-left: 400px;padding-top: 200px;padding-right: 400px;"><p style="    line-height: 130%; padding-left: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;background: white; border-radius: 15px; border-style: groove"><b>Aufgabe 3</b><br><br>

some text....
<br><br>

<a href="Hoffest.jpg" download="Hoffest.jpg">
  <img src="Hoffest.jpg" width="150" height="120">
</a>

<br><br>

some more text...
<br><br><button type="button" id="weiter" value="weiter"  style="font-size : 26px; width: 9%; height: 36px; border-radius: 7px"
                 onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'test' ) }}'">weiter</button></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html file, I can see  some text and a view of the image  as well. And when I click on the image, l expect it to be downloaded like in the link above. but instead a click opens this image file on the same tab,changing from my html-file. I tried doing it with a button too. So instead of `<img src="Hoffest.jpg" width="150" height="120">` I put `<button>Download Image</button>`. The same thing happened. When I clicked on the button it just opened the image on the same tab without downloading it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this over HTTP or is the URL a `file:` scheme one?

Comment: Which Browser? [caniuse/download](https://caniuse.com/#search=download)

Comment: try changing `download='hoffest.jpg'` to just `download`.

Comment: @Rojo — Why? I'm not aware of any browser which supports `download` without a value but ignores it completely if there is a value.

Comment: that happens in chrome and firefox. i didnt try the other browsers. it has to work on these two browsers only.

Comment: @rojo, i have tried that. didnt help

Comment: @Rojo The `download` attribute does accept a value : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: Is your image on the same domain / origin ? The `download` attribute only works if the link href an the current web page are on the same origin.

Comment: yea my html file and the image file are in the same folder, if that's what you were asking. otherwise I wouldn't be able to see the preview of my image on the html. But I do.

Comment: You *can* see images from an other domain. You just need the other server to allow cross origin requests (like Gravatar or Imgur do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your answer to my comment, I assume you are trying this directly by opening an HTML file in your browser.

the `download` attribute has a strong limit on the origin. It has to be the same (except for `blob:` and `data:` schemes), but it also won't work if you are opening the file directly (with `file://`)

What you can do is run a local HTTP server (personally I use the npm package [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), or you can run a classic web server like Apache or Nginx) and access your file through the server, with the HTTP protocol.